# How to import/export functions between different NPM packages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've a React NPM package I'm developing as a framework for many of my other projects.  Let's call this package "framework".  Then I have a framework consumer.

So in the framework consumer project, I can run the following code:

and then I can use said framework like this, passing props to customize:

```
import Framework from 'framework'
export default function App() {
    return (
            <>
            <Framework
                appName="My App Name"
                logoImagePath={"/images/MyApp_logo.png"}
            />
            <OtherComponent />
            </>
    )
}
```

This works well.

However, I want to be able to call functions that the Framework can provide.  For example, let's say the Framework contains modals and has a `setErrorMessage` and I want to be able to have something in `OtherComponent` call a the `setErrorMessage` function.

How would I do this?

I'd like my OtherComponent to be able to do something like:

```
import {setErrorMessage} from 'framework'
export default function OtherComponent() {
    return <button onClick={()=>setErrorMessage("Stop, Error time!")}>Fire an error</button>
}
```

(of note, setErrorMessage is actually a setter function inside a context of Framework... but the idea is more conceptual.  If I have a function in an npm package, how do I expose it to consumers?)